# Name of slightly-less-than-2mm pin connector?

Tags: connector, pins

I have a couple of these: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Automatic-meter-reading-Lora-low-power_60213414513.html

The pins are such that a 2mm female connector will nearly fit - i.e. the pins are slightly closer than 2mm.

What is this connector called and what is it's dimensions?  Is it non-metric?

Comment: If you get yourself a digital caliper you will be able to measure it yourself and then search for connectors with the same pitch.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called RMC female connectors.

I think this link shows the connector you are looking for, but you should find a 7-pin for yourself.

http://www.rhydolabz.com/hardwares-connectorssockets-c-170_77/4-pin-rmc-female-connector-with-wire-2mm-pitch-p-2345.html

Comment: No, the asker explicitly says the pitch is *not* 2mm.